# ios/swift - Putting a subview behind the superView?

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect, subviews

I have a `TraceView` which draws a bunch of stuff in the `draw(rect)` method, and I have `AxisView` which is added as a subview to the `TraceView`. The `TraceView` also draws a bunch of stuff in its own `draw(rect)` method. The problem is that the stuff that I draw on the `AxisView` is showing up on top of the stuff of the I have drawn on the `TraceView`. Even after I call `self.sendSubview(toBack: axisView)`, where `self` is my `TraceView` isntance.

Is there any way to fix this without having to redo the layout structure?

Comment: I think you're fighting against the definition of subviews.  If your two views are peers, you can control the Z-order by where they are in the superview's array of subviews.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot fix this without changing your view (or layer) hierarchy. A view's content always appears in front of the content of its ancestors.